# os.getenv doesn't work as default value for a function parameter if set within python

Tags: python, parameters, environment-variables

With the following code, I'd expect func1 to print the host value (5000) I set twice.

```py
import os

def func1(host = os.getenv("HOST")):
    print(host)
    print(os.getenv("HOST"))

os.environ["HOST"] = "5000"
func1()
```

#### Output:

```
None
5000
```

Strange. Let's check the whole list of env vars.

```
def func2(env = os.environ):
    print(env)

os.environ["HOST"] = "5000"
func2()
```

#### Output:

```
environ({..., 'Host': '5000'})
```

Okay, very strange, so can I grab it using environ?

```
def func3(host = os.environ["HOST"]):
    print(host)

os.environ["HOST"] = "5000"
func3()
```

#### Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest.py", line 10, in <module>
    def func3(host = os.environ["HOST"]):
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'HOST'
```

Am I missing something, or this this a bug with python?

Comment: The default value is evaluated when the function is *defined*, not called. The default value of `host` is `None`, since `HOST` hasn't been defined yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function default values are evaluated when the function is *defined*. If you add a line to your script

```
import os


print(os.getenv("HOST"))


def func1(host = os.getenv("HOST")):
    print(host)
    print(os.getenv("HOST"))


os.environ["HOST"] = "5000"
func1()
```

you'll get a preview of what the default value of the `host` parameter will be. It's the value of `HOST` as inherited from the parent process, or `None` if `HOST` isn't currently in the environment at all.

Comment: Well that would make sense for the most part. However, why would the second code block (func2) have "HOST" within os.environ?

Comment: Because you explicitly add the variable to the environment *after* you define the function, but *before* you call it. The two calls to `os.getenv` happen at two different times.

Comment: I mean, this one. Shouldn't env not contain "HOST"?

`def func2(env = os.environ):
    print(env)

os.environ["HOST"] = "5000"
func2()`

Comment: `os.environ` is just a reference to the mutable environment, not a copy of the environment as it exists when the function is defined. It doesn't contain `HOST` when you define the function, but it does when you call it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default values are set at runtime not when the function is called. So if you were to set the environment variable above the function declaration it would work.

```
import os

os.environ["test"] = "test"

def foo(bar=os.environ["test"]):
     print(bar)
     print(os.environ["test"])

foo()
```

Output:

```
test
test
```